# 4th grade Probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

lisa has a bag with mables, $3$ yellow marbles, $6$ purple marbles, and $2$ green marbles.  If she randomly pulls one marble from the bag $36$ times, which color is she most likely to pull $12$ times?

Comment: Nice problem. Understanding the words might be the tough part for a grade $4$ student.

Comment: A word of "warning": IIRC in the US fourth graders are 9-year-olds or something like that. "Grade" may mean something else somewhere else. But yeah. Sigh.

Comment: The marbles are picked with replacement.

Answer (score 4):

Intuitively, since the probability of drawing a yellow marble is closest to $\frac{12}{36}$, we expect that the answer should be yellow.

More precisely, and more generally, suppose event $A$ occurs with probability $p$, and given $N$ trials we'd like to know the probability, $P$, that event $A$ occurs exactly $n\le N$ times.  This is given by the equation:
$$P=\binom{N}{n}\cdot p^n\cdot(1-p)^{N-n}$$
The binomial coefficient accounts for the different trials in which $A$ may occur.  For this problem, $N=36$, $n=12$, and $p$ depends on which color we take for event $A$.  Let's explicitly calculate the probability for yellow, leaving the rest for you to try on your own.

In the case that event $A$ represents drawing a yellow marble, we have $p=\frac{3}{11}$.  It follows that
$$P=\binom{36}{12}\left(\frac{3}{11}\right)^{12}\left(\frac{8}{11}\right)^{24}\approx .1016$$

Try to verify our original suspicion by calculating the probabilities for purple and green marbles.